# Which polynomial will give the minimum value on given x.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, maxima-minima

We are given n polynomials $p_1(x), p_2(x), \dotsc, p_n(x)$. Each polynomials is of the form $p(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are whole numbers up to $10^5$. We are given $x_0$. And we have to find $p_i(x)$ such that $p_i(x)$ has minimum value among all $n$ polynomials.

Comment: What is wrong with just evaluating them and keeping the minimum as you go?  I don't see anything better.  Presumably you want pi(x0) to be minimum among the polynomials.

Comment: Want an approach that can work for multiple values of x0, also answer a query in minimum time.

Comment: For each x0 there could well be a different one that is minimal.  You clearly have to look at each polynomial to find the minimum.  You could look at pairs and find the crossover points, but that is quadratic in the number of polynomials.  It could be efficient if there are many x0 values.

Comment: Yeah there are different answer for each value of x0.

Comment: I'm confused... do you mean $\pi(x_0)$?

Comment: @XanderHenderson:  no, he means $p_i(x_0)$, which of the polynomials takes the lowest value.

Comment: no it is p is polynomial function which is in form ax^3+bx^2+cx+d.

Comment: Oi... this is why proper typesetting matters...  That being said, I'm still confused by the question, since $x_0$ is given, but never used.  Do you mean $p_i(x_0)$?

Comment: Do you *really* need to find the minimizing polynomial, or is it enough to prove that some polynomial attains a minimum $\leq 10^{-15}$ (assuming that $x$ is trascendental over $\mathbb{Q}$)? The latter is just a consequence of the pigeonhole/Dirichlet's box principle.

Comment: need minimum polynomial.

Comment: Then unless some of the continued fractions of $x,x^2,x^3$ show a great regularity, I do not see a more efficient approach than brute force (I agree with Ross Millikan).